# App to take notes and save sources

Tags: osx, note-taking

I'm working on a research project and ideally, looking for something that would allow me to type notes and save / easily pull up the webpages where the information was obtained from. I don't want to manually put links in the text to avoid clutter. Is there an app for Mac that can do this seamlessly? Thank you!

Comment: Browser bookmarks usually offer a comment field for notes, so that would be the simplest match. Sorry, but your description is a bit vague.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am looking for something that connects to note taking. Say, an app where I could write "The Empire State Building is located in New York" and be easily able to access a website that supports this fact by hovering over or clicking on part of this text or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that both Microsoft OneNote and Evernote offers features that meet your criteria.

Another serious tool for this kind of thing is DEVONthink. I haven’t personally used it, but I found the following article to be very persuasive.

https://medium.com/@YRousse/quitting-evernote-adopting-devonthink-608472d9f455

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would try Evernote.

Evernote has a webclipper that you can use on chrome. It let’s you clip articles by taking a screenshot - annotating it, extracting simple text, or bookmark. It saves the link source.

On the app itself(web, mac, mobile) you can highlight text, edit, link to other notes you create or clip. There are so many features that I think would benefit your research.

[Here is a list of all their features.](https://evernote.com/get-started?utm_source=google&utm_campaign=cpc&utm_campaign=2018_Search_Brand_USA_EM&utm_content=Evernote_Features&utm_keyword=373200752856&gclid=CjwKCAjwwJrbBRAoEiwAGA1B_a6vFBAxgfsTBRT1Ocu1uZkwIPQuAexz6V19N1knMYksmcSW2am90hoCR4kQAvD_BwE)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the Note app that comes with the system software. This app appears in your dock. I leave it open whenever I'm on my iMac. If I need to make a note I click the app in the dock and it brings up my current note page. I can quickly type my note there. If I highlight a word in the app and then right click, it will do internet searches on that word if you wish. This app can also store everything on iCloud so available on iPhone and iPad if desired.

Answer (score 0):

[Quiver](http://happenapps.com) 
is great for this, my go-to  note app

[image]